# Multiple Forms C# - Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

I have a problem... I try to use 2 forms (The second - administratorForm - is opened after i click a button on the first - loginForm).
On the main form (loginForm), i did something like this:

```
administratorForm administratorFormular = new administratorForm();
if (usernameTextBox.Text == "administrator" && passwordTextBox.Text == "administrator")
{
    administratorFormular.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Then, on the second form(administratorForm), i have this:

```
loginForm loginFormular = new loginForm();
private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loginFormular.Close();
}
```

I get an error for entering in an infinite loop (i guess it is because I declared the both forms, one in each other). How can I solve this?

Any help will appriciated...

// L.E.:
Login Form:

```
public partial class loginForm : Form
{
    administratorForm administratorFormular = new administratorForm();

    public loginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usernameTextBox.Text == "administrator" && passwordTextBox.Text == "administrat0r")
        {
            administratorFormular.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (usernameTextBox.Text == "player" && passwordTextBox.Text == "pl4yer")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password!");
            usernameTextBox.Text = "";
            passwordTextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Administrator Form:

```
public partial class administratorForm : Form
{
    loginForm loginFormular = new loginForm();

    public administratorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginFormular.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post complete methods where you use above code?

Comment: new creates a *new* instance, you need to reference your existing form.

Comment: Pass the instance of the `loginForm` to the constructor of `administratorForm` which you have to create or overload `administratorFormular.Show(loginForm login)`.

Comment: Please show more code; although it seems that Sayse's comment already addresses the problem. Apparently the problem is not an infinite loop but a method call on the wrong instance.

Comment: I edited it. I added the full code of the 2 forms (excepting includes and namespace, to make it shorter).
@Sayse, How can i reference to my existing form?

Comment: @AlinP25: my last comment explains two ways. Store the passed instance into your variable then.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, i don't understand it. :( I guess this is not for me... I got stucked so fast.

Comment: Your loginForm creates an administratorForm.  Your administratorForm creates a loginForm.  That new loginForm creates an administratorForm.  That new administratorForm creates a loginForm.  That new loginForm creates an administratorForm.  That new administratorForm creates a loginForm.  That new loginForm creates an administratorForm.  That new administratorForm creates a loginForm. That ... Kaboom!!!

Comment: @HansPassant, i got it... But how do I solve it? I'm new in C#.

Comment: The way to go is @TimSchmelter. But another way is just not initialize your administratorFormular until the loginbutton_click. So, in your  LoginForm you define `administratorForm administratorFormular;` and then, in your loginButton_Click you do this : `administratorFormular = new administratorForm(); administratorFormular.Show();`

Comment: There is no point whatsover in letting the administratorForm create a new instance of loginForm.  Delete that code, it is wrong.  Then ask the question about the *real* problem you are trying to solve.  It has been asked before btw.

Comment: I've added an answer which will stop the infinite loop, but it won't stop the fact that you can't close the parent form from a child, but I'll let you figure that one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Writing `loginFormular().Close();` write `this.Hide();` and then Create the instance of other form if it is compulsory

Comment: I want it to close the app, that's why I wrote .Close().

Comment: then instead you should write, `Application.Exit();` :)

Comment: I didn't knew about that. Thanks a lot. You saved my life :O

Comment: You are Welcome bro, don't forget to rate the answer :)

Comment: I did, but it tells me that i need 15 reputation points, or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition `administratorForm`, the line

```
loginForm loginFormular = new loginForm();
```

creates a new instance of `loginForm` which is never replaced. One possibility to fix this is to declare `loginFormular` as `public` in `administratorFormular`, initialize it with `null` and add

```
administratorFormular.loginFormular = this;
administratorFormular.Show();
this.Hide();
```

in `loginButton_Click` in `loginForm` to give the `administratorFormular` a reference to the the desired `loginForm`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a reference to the parent form when creating the second form

```
loginForm loginFormular;

public administratorForm(loginForm form)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loginFormular = form;
}
```

and call it as you need it (on the login form) with

```
new administratorForm(this);
```

there isn't really any need to define it as a property of the login form.

Note: this is only if you actually need the parent form, the code you've shown doesn't actually use it at all and if so, just delete any references to the login form in this second form.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try to figure out how to use "new" better.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code does the following (as described in the comment above):
Your `loginForm` instance creates an instance of `administratorForm`, which then creates an instance of `loginForm`, which then continues the cycle.

To avoid this, you create the `administratorForm` instance once you need it and pass the instance of `loginForm` to the newly created `administartorForm`.

The code would look like this:

```
public partial class loginForm : Form
{
    // administratorForm administratorFormular = new administratorForm();

    public loginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usernameTextBox.Text == "administrator" && passwordTextBox.Text == "administrat0r")
        {
            var administratorFormular = new administratorForm();
            administratorFormular.loginFormular = this;
            administratorFormular.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (usernameTextBox.Text == "player" && passwordTextBox.Text == "pl4yer")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password!");
            usernameTextBox.Text = "";
            passwordTextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
}

public partial class administratorForm : Form
{
    // loginForm loginFormular = new loginForm();

    public loginFormular LoginForm;

    public administratorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginFormular.Close();
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense to you.

I am currently unable to test this, but it might be possible to just `Close()` the `loginForm` and not pass it at all after you have `Show()`n your `administratorForm`.

In that case, you don't have to pass the `loginForm` instance over to the administratorForm and call `this.Close();` instead of `this.Hide();`, and remove the `loginFormular.Close();` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In your Program.cs Class of your WinForms-project:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        DialogResult res = loginForm.ShowDialog();
        if (res != DialogResult.OK)
            return;
        if (loginForm.MyEnumCode == 1)
        { //AdminForm
            Application.Run(new AdminForm());
        }
        else if (loginForm.MyEnumCode == 2)
        { //PlayerForm
            Application.Run(new PlayerForm());
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the LoginForm code:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public int MyEnumCode = 0;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textUser.Text == "administrator" && textPass.Text == "administrat0r")
        {
            MyEnumCode = 1;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else if (textUser.Text == "player" && textPass.Text == "pl4yer")
        {
            MyEnumCode = 2;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password!");
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

if you set this.DialogResult to any value, the Form will automatically close. you can then check if the result is your desired result (in our case it should be 'OK') and get the EnumCode from your loginForm. You should use an Enum rather than just an int, but int works fine too.

Comment: If you are going for this approach, you could just check for loginForm.DialogResult and leave out the MyEnumCode entirely.

Comment: if you leave out the MyEnumCode, you can't Switch between admin and Player Login. if it would be just a simple Login form, then you're right about it.

Comment: Well, in your example, it wouldn't make sense, as the form instance is created in the method and destroyed at the end, so you can just as well use the DialogResult property there.